# How to Split an activerecord query to increase speed

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

any help would be really appreciated.

I have an active record query that I am performing that is running really slowly now that there are a lot of records in the table.

I am thinking of splitting the function into a few separate queries and then joining them after. Although I'm not sure of the best way to go about it. I am searching the users and profile tables twice currently so I now there are some improvements that can be made.

I've attached the activerecord query below, if I've not made anything clear let me know and I'll edit my question.

Thanks in advance.

```
$this->db->select(
    'stage_one_application.id as application_id,
    stage_one_application.proposal_title as title, 
    stage_one_application.proposal_abstract, 
    category.faq_category_title as category,
    stage_one_application.proposal_category_alt 
        AS category_freetext, 
    stage_one_application.pooling as pool, 
    user.id as user_id, 
    profile.first_name, 
    profile.last_name, 
    profile.date_of_birth, 
    stage_one_application.admin_feasibility 
        AS feasibility_score, 
    stage_one_application.admin_innovation 
        AS innovation_score, 
    stage_one_application.admin_technical_excellence 
        AS technical_excellence_score, 
    stage_one_application.application_accepted 
        AS through_to_stage_two, 
    rev_profile.first_name AS reviewer_firstname, 
    rev_profile.last_name as reviewer_lastname, 
    application_stage_one_scoring.innovation 
        AS reviewer_score_innovation, 
    application_stage_one_scoring.feasibility 
        AS reviewer_score_feasibility, 
    application_stage_one_scoring.technical_excellence 
        AS reviewer_score_technical_excellence,
    application_stage_one_scoring.application_stage_one_reviewer_comment 
        AS reviewer_comment'
);
$this->db->from('stage_one_application');
$this->db->join('users as user', 'user.id = stage_one_application.candidate_id');
$this->db->join(
    'profiles as profile', 
    'profile.user_id = stage_one_application.candidate_id'
);
$this->db->join(
    'faq_categories as category', 
    'category.id = stage_one_application.proposal_category'
);
$this->db->join(
    'application_stage_one_scoring',
    'application_stage_one_scoring.application_stage_one_id = stage_one_application.id',
    'left'
);
$this->db->join(
    'users as reviewer', 
    'reviewer.id = application_stage_one_scoring.application_stage_one_scoring_reviewer'
);
$this->db->join(
'profiles as rev_profile', 
'rev_profile.user_id=application_stage_one_scoring.application_stage_one_scoring_reviewer'
);
$this->db->order_by("application_id", "desc"); 
$query = $this->db->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not a CodeIgniter problem, I think. You need to optimize Your database, because on each query SQL-server creates large temp-table (joining procedure). Try to check INDEXes and if they used correctly, create VIEW at database and ask what You need from it.